# Unable to add textfield entered text in json post request parameter while parsing in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, text, uitextfield

Initially i am getting textfield text from previous viewcontroller to know what text to add in present view controller. if i tap in textfield previous text is going to be empty and i am adding text but that text i am unable to add present view controller post parameter.. here also i am getting previous view controller text.

here is my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var cell : BillerTableViewCell?
var textFieldArray = [String]()
var selectedBiller: JsonDataBiller?
var toplabeText: String?

var textFieldValue: String?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as! BillerTableViewCell

        cell?.searchTextfield.delegate = self

        if let param = selectedBiller?.bcustomerparms[indexPath.row] {
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = param.paramName
            textFieldValue = cell?.searchTextfield.text
        } else {
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = "missing data"
        }

    return cell!
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    billerFetchService()
}

func billerFetchService(){


    print("fetch paramname \(textFieldKey)")
    // var textFieldValue: String = (cell?.searchTextfield.text)!


    let parameters = ["billDetails": [
        "billerId" : "EPDCLOB00ANP01",
        "customerParams" : [["name": textFieldKey,"value": textFieldValue]]]] as [String : Any]

    print("the textfield value is  \(textFieldValue)")
    let url = URL(string: "https://app.com/emi_v1/fetch")
    var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
    req.httpBody = httpBody
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if response != nil {
            // print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do{
                var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                // print("fetching json \(json)")
                let fetchStatus = json["status"] as? String

                if fetchStatus == "sucess"{
                    let billerDetails = json["response"] as! [String:Any]
                    let value = billerDetails["billerResponse"] as! String
                    print(value)

                    let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:Data(value.utf8)) as! [String: Any]
                    self.billerName = res["billerName"] as? String
                    var consumName = res["customerName"] as? String

                    print("fetch only APEPDCL biller name \(self.billerName)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FetchBillerViewController") as? FetchBillerViewController
                        nextViewController?.nameText = self.billerName
                        nextViewController?.consumrName = consumName
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController!, animated: true)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Invalid service Number", in: self)
                    }
                }
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
}
```

Comment: Directly use textfield.text! to get your value. whats the need of using KeychainWrapper?

Comment: @KeshuRai, i am not using ketchain, that is for another field... i hav deleted that line

Comment: Ok. let finalString = yourTextField.text! .. now pass this finalString in your request

Comment: @KeshuRai, if textfield is in view than its going, but textfield is in tableview thats why.. please help

Comment: @KeshuRai, plese once look at my `cellForRowAt `... how to add

Comment: Ok. answering the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a variable in your view controller that will store the final value.

```
var finalSearchValue : String = ""
```

Now in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method add this line:

```
cell.searchFieldText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Now in your view controller declare this function:

```
@objc func searchEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) { 
 finalSearchValue = textField.text!
}
```

thats it. your finalSearchValue variable now contains the input text. Use it for your api request.

Let me know if any issue.

Comment: :) glad to help